# If statement does not work properly unless I use a debugger to step through it. Using pytube

Tags: python, pytube

I'm using pytube to convert a url that is for sure a link to a YouTube playlist into a pytube.Playlist()

```
if "/playlist?list=" in url:
        playlist = Playlist(url)
        if len(playlist.video_urls._elements) == 0:
                print("Some error message")
```

The problem is that the playlist I'm using to test this has about 300 videos in it, so this `if` statement should be skipped, but instead, it goes into it and prints the error message. So naturally, I went to check it out with the debugger, and for some reason, once I start stepping into the code, it works the way it should and skips the `if` statement.

Anyone know what might be the problem?

IDE: Visual Studio Code

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Is there another thread updating the list?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Playlist.video_urls` is a *`DeferredGeneratorList`*](https://pytube.io/en/latest/_modules/pytube/contrib/playlist.html#Playlist), not a list. So until you iterate over it, it doesn't have a length.

```py
@property  # type: ignore
@cache
def video_urls(self) -> DeferredGeneratorList:
    """Complete links of all the videos in playlist
    
    :rtype: List[str]
    :returns: List of video URLs
    """
    return DeferredGeneratorList(self.url_generator())
```

Moreover, you're checking the length of `_elements` which is private to the class/API. And it's [initialised to an empty list](https://pytube.io/en/stable/_modules/pytube/helpers.html) so it's length is always initially zero.

So either call `len()` on `playlist.video_urls` or better, use the provided method to populate the list `generate_all()` or just call `list()` on it.

**The reason it works in your debugger is that the debugger tries to access the elements of the list to find its length, which triggers the iteration and populates it.**

Good on you for at least trying the debugger and noticing the difference in behaviour for normal execution vs debugger execution! +1

And instead of checking the length, just iterate over it and check if anything was done, with a flag value:

```py
if "/playlist?list=" in url:
    playlist = Playlist(url)
    had_videos = False  # initial value
    for video in playlist.video_urls:
        had_videos = True  # if exec gets here, you had at least one vid
        # do something with each `video`
    if not had_videos:
        print("Some error message")
```